# How to parse 00:00.00000 to TimeSpan?

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

I try to parse string via c#:

```
  var tm = TimeSpan.ParseExact(00:00.00000, "hh:mm.sssss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

and then get TotalMilliseconds, but i get FormatException.

How to do that?

Comment: That *is* an invalid format. You can't have 5 second digits.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, and if it is milliseconds?

Comment: @AdmiralLand Then you would do `hh:mm.ss.fff` Your time parameter needs to change too.. `00:00.00000` should become `00:00.00.000`

Comment: Post what you actually want to do. Do you *really* have a string containing only minuetes and seconds? No hours? The snippet you posted here won't even compile

Comment: Looks like `@"mm\:ss\.fffff"`, but with only zeroes it's hard to tell.

Comment: `TimeSpan.ParseExact("00:00.00000", "mm\\:ss\\.fffff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` will work. As the duplicate question and [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings#other-characters) shows, any character that isn't a format specifier, including separators, needs escaping

Comment: That's not an arbitrary restriction either. The format patterns are the same for formatting and parsing. `:` is used to separate arguments from format strings. The same pattern can be used in `String.Format("{0:mm\\:ss\\.fffff}", TimeSpan.Zero)`. This would break if `:` wasn't escaped

Comment: @JeroenMostert, i have log file with timestamp:00:00.05601 , and it is mm:ss:milliseconds

Comment: @JeroenMostert, i solve it by parse 00000 as milliseconds and 00:00 as mm\\:ss. And then sum it.

Comment: var ts = TimeSpan.ParseExact(val, "mm\\:ss\\.fffff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);